# SQL Query to find difference in hours between first and last records of each day for a month, and sum each difference to find the total

Tags: sql, sql-server

This isn't the easiest query to describe in one sentence which is why the title might not be the best.

Basically I have a log of sign-ins. This log looks like:

```
ContactId, LocationId, TimeStamp
```

These represent a Contact (registered person) being seen at a location at a given time.

What I want to do it pick a datetime window, and for each day in that window I want to take the first sign-in, and the last sign-in and work out the difference in hours. This difference in hours should then contribute to an overall total, giving an estimate of the total time the Contact spent at the location during the month.

Days when the Contact was not seen should obviously be ignored, and days when the Contact was seen only once should not be used either as no difference can be calculated.

I know how to find the difference between two datetimes in hours:

```
select DATEDIFF(HOUR, datetime1, datetime2) as hoursestimate
```

But I'm not sure how to:

1. Make datetime1 and datetime2 the first and last record of a day.
2. Loop through the data increasing the day count to find a cumulative total of hours (TotalHours) over the month.

Once I have the cumulative hours total over the time period based on the first and last seen difference I will perform a join with my contact table to obtain their first and last name and order by this TotalHours column, so hopefully the final table I want to be returned from the query will be something like:

```
Id    FirstName     LastName     TotalHours
35     Bob          Bobberson    65
40     Jim          Jimmerson    63
2      Harry        Harrison     54
```

It's steps 1 and 2 that I'm a bit lost on however. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want two aggregations:

```
select contactid, sum(hoursestimate) as total
from (select contactid, cast(TimeStamp as date) as dte,
             DATEDIFF(HOUR, min(TimeStamp), max(TimeStamp)) as hoursestimate
      from t
      where TimeStamp >= @start and TimeStamp < @end
      group by contactid, cast(TimeStamp as date)
     ) t
group by contactid;
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly! I'm not the best with SQL but I follow what you've done and I think I learnt something! Cheers for the speedy response too.

Comment: the answer below uses a having statement to ignore contacts we've only seen once during the day. What is occuring in this query when the contact has been see once? I assume the min and max are the same so there is no contributing hours to the total?

Comment: You can, of course, filter out the 0 contributing hours.  Just add where hoursestimate <> 0 to the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of different techniques that can help you here.

[CAST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) will let you strip the date and time sections of the date time stamp from each other.  This is really handy for grouping multiple records from the same day, but different times, together.

The [HAVING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms180199.aspx) can be used to filter out contacts with only record in a day.  This works by counting the number of contributing records, and removing those below your threshold.

This example combines those techniques:

[Exmaple](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/403445/time-difference-example)

```
WITH SampleDate AS
    (
        /* Lets make some records to experiment with.
         */
        SELECT
            r.*
        FROM
            (
                VALUES
                    (1, 1, '2015-01-01 09:00:00.000'),
                    (1, 1, '2015-01-01 12:00:00.000'),
                    (1, 1, '2015-01-01 17:00:00.000'),
                    (2, 1, '2015-01-01 09:00:00.000')
            ) AS r(ContactId, LocationId, [TimeStamp])
    )
SELECT
    ContactId, 
    LocationId,
    CAST([TimeStamp] AS DATE)                AS [Day],    
    MIN(CAST([TimeStamp] AS TIME))            AS FirstSeenTime,
    MAX(CAST([TimeStamp] AS TIME))            AS LastSeenTime,    
    DATEDIFF(
        HOUR,
        MIN(CAST([TimeStamp] AS TIME)),
        MAX(CAST([TimeStamp] AS TIME))
    )                                        AS HoursEstimate
FROM
    SampleDate
GROUP BY
    ContactId, 
    LocationId,
    CAST([TimeStamp] AS DATE)        -- Removing the time allows us to create 1 record per day.
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1                    -- Make sure we've seen the contact at least twice.
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and explanation. The main difference in answers is the Having statement....Could you explain what is occuring in the other answer when we have seen the contact only once on the given day? I'm worried it may be inaccurate with the absence of the Having statement, but it's hard to tell by just looking at my data output. @ReleaseObject

Comment: I assume the min and max are the same so there is no contributing hours to the total?

Comment: Yes you are right.  The min and max would be the same, creating an estimated time of 0 hours.